# Is projective space really a moduli space for lines through the origin?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, moduli-space

The [Wikipedia page for Moduli spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_space) states that real projective space $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is a moduli space which parametrizes the space of lines in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ passing through the origin.  However, any line $L$ passing through the origin in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ has non-trivial automorphisms given by stretching the line (i.e., those linear transformations which have $L$ as an eigenvector).  It's well known that the existence of non-trivial automorphisms precludes the existence of a moduli space.  What is going on here?

Comment: In general terms what precludes the existence of a moduli space is not non-trivial automorphisms per-se but sudden jumps in particular objects in a family. For example in the case of elliptic curves the reason a (coarse) moduli space doesn't exist is that special curves have more automorphisms than others. In fact if you removed these special curves then you have a nice moduli space. In the projective line example the point is all lines have the same automorphism group that is $GL_{1}$ there are no jumps.

Comment: That is why in some sense Grassmanians are outliers because the problems with constructing moduli spaces in general are never present in Grassmanian example. The elliptic curve example is far more enlightening. The book Moduli of Curves by Harris and Morrison discuses some very simple (but artificial) examples ti illustrate this point.